# QGIS 3.22.4: Exported A0 sized GeoPDF not displaying all polygon data

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, geopdf

I generate A0 geoPDFs that contain polygon data for landholders to use when undertaking clearing activities. The landholder uses these maps in Avenza.

Recently (~May 2022 onward) I have noticed that the print composed maps are not displaying all the polygon data i.e. some of the polygons are missing in the final product. However, export a non georeferenced PDF and all the data is present. This appears to be an issue confined to small scale maps/ large properties. I have tried layering and the different options available when printing to PDF to no avail.

This was not an apparent issue prior to this as I have been creating these maps for 18mths.

As can be seen in the snips below of a geoPDF and non-geo PDF exported from print composer, there is a lot of missing data. This is a portion of a desired map covering 91000ha.

I have the solution of exporting to TIF but these are significantly larger files (40 vs 300mb).

Is anyone aware of this issue and can someone provide assistance? I can only think it is an issue with adobe. I cannot provide specific data due to privacy issues but can point people in the direction of example data.

[image: geoPDF]

[image: non-geo PDF]